# Unix sed command to insert a new line with same space indentation before the matching string in yaml file

Tags: unix, sed

Please guide for the unix sed command to insert a new line with same space indentation before the matching string in yaml file

Sample:

```
Input:
  paths:
    - /IBGM/monitor/logs/health_metrics_2*log
  fields:
    type: health_check_metrics
    application: IBGM
    app_host: xxx

Output:
  paths:
    - /IBGM/monitor/logs/health_metrics_2*log
  ignore_older: 24h
  fields:
    type: health_check_metrics
    application: IBGM
    app_host: xxx


# echo "  fields:" | sed '/^[[:space:]]*fields:.*/i  ignore_older: 24h'
Output:
ignore_older: 24h
  fields:
```

How to preserve the space on the first line similar to the second line

Comment: Using regex to manipulate structured formats is always a bad idea. Try a YAML-aware tool like `yq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempted solution is almost there.  You just need to capture the initial spaces/tabs:

```
  echo "  fields:" | sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*\)\(fields:\)/\1ignore_older: 24h\n\1\2/'
```

Explanation:

- `s/^\([[:space:]]*\)\(fields:\)` if a line begins with zero or more spaces and "fields:"
- `/\1ignore_older: 24h\n\1\2/` add a new line consisting of spaces and "ignore_older: 24h"

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*fields:/{h;s/\S.*/ignore_older: 24h/;G}' file
```

Find the line you want to insert before and make a copy in the hold space. Replace everything in the current line from the first non-white space character to the end of the line by the required string. Append the copied line to the amended line.